# Regular expression to catch start and end whitespaces between square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression in javascript which will fail in cases when string is something like:

```
foo[ bar]
foo[bar ]
foo[ bar ]
```

`foo` can be any word (also can contain special characters as `-` and `.`), same goes for `bar`.

It should not fail if string is just:

```
[ bar]
[bar ]
[ bar ]
```

And should not fail if string is:

```
foo[bar]
```

A bit of background info. I am writing a custom linter rule which will fail if the referenced array has unneeded spaces in brackets. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is what I have so far ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BDXevG/2)):

```
\[([^\]]+)\]
```

But this catches the whole bracket into account and does not evaluate the beginning (it should be preceeded). Also, it should evaluate the presence of whitespaces only.

Comment: @Xufox I've updated the question.

Comment: Should `foo [bar ]` or `foo [bar]` fail?

Comment: @banan3'14 yes.

Comment: You may use capturing groups to your advantage. Use `/\w+\[(\s[^\]]+|[^\]]*\s)]|\w*\[([^\]]+)]/g` and check if Group 1 matched. If yes, skip these matches, else process.

Comment: Your test cases in regex101 should fail or succeed?

Comment: @revo I've updated the regex examples with comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only want to match strings that 1) have 1 or more word chars before `(` and 2) have whitespace right after `[` or right before `]`.

You may use

```
/\w+\[(\s[^\]]*|[^\]]*\s)]/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r95Rnx/2).

**Details**

- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `\[` - a `[`
- `(\s[^\]]*|[^\]]*\s)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\s[^\]]*` - a whitespace char followed with 0+ chars other than `]`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^\]]*\s` - 0+ chars other than `]` followed with a whitespace char
- `]` - a `]` char.

JS demo:

```js
var rx = /\w+\[(\s[^\]]*|[^\]]*\s)]/;
var strs = [ "foo[ bar]", "foo[bar ]", "foo[ bar ]", "[ bar]", "[bar ]", "[ bar ]"];
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit mundane but:

```
var rgx = /^(?:\w|[_\-.])+?\[(?:\w|[_\-.])+\]|^\[\s*(?:\w|[_\-.])+\s*\]/gi;
```

seems to work for your cases:

```
var rgx = /^(?:\w|[_\-.])+?\[(?:\w|[_\-.])+\]|^\[\s*(?:\w|[_\-.])+\s*\]/i;
["foo[ bar]","foo[bar ]","foo[ bar ]","[ bar]","[bar ]","[ bar ]","foo[bar]"]
.forEach(function(d,i){console.log(rgx.test(d))});
    //false x 3
    //true x 4
```

Comment: Nice approach, what should be the opposite match? So the false true would be reversed. See: https://regex101.com/r/d6m07Z/1/

Comment: It depends on what you mean by opposite. Something like "foo   [bar]" ? Or any string that fails the rgx? For the latter one, `!rgx.test(someString)` would suffice I guess.

Comment: So: `"someLong\nlong\nfoo[bar]\nsentence".split(/\n/g).filter(function(d,i){return !rgx.test(d)})` will give you the reverse

Comment: What I meant is that I want to run this test simply as: `rgx.test("lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"); // false`, `rgx.test("foo[bar]"); // false` and `rgx.test("foo[ bar]"); // true`. Makes sense?

Comment: @Janez Use `/\w+\[(\s[^\]]+|[^\]]*\s)]/.test(str)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `/\[\s+[a-zA-Z0-9._]|[a-zA-Z0-9._]\s+\]/g`:

```js
function test(str){
  var regex = /\[\s+[a-zA-Z0-9._]|[a-zA-Z0-9._]\s+\]/g;
  if(str.match(regex))
   return 'Passed';
  else
    return 'Failed';
}

//Passed
console.log(test('foo[ bar]'));
console.log(test('foo[bar ]'));
console.log(test('foo[ bar ]'));
console.log(test('foo[.bar ]'));
console.log(test('foo[ bar- ]'));
//Failed
console.log(test('foo[bar]'));
```

Comment: This won't work in the general case, as *`foo` can be any word (also can contain special characters as `-` and `.`), same goes for `bar`.*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I have updated the answer with those special character in the regex......thanks